# Delta indexing the elastic search index on change of model's association record value change using Tire and Elastic Search

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, associations, elasticsearch, tire, delta-index

I am a newbie to elastic Search and Tire in Ruby on Rails. Watched the railscasts from ryan bates and helped me to get going. Tire is a great gem and has functionality to delta indexing. Assuming i have a mapping like the following, will Tire automatically delta index the model associations if an association value is edited/ deleted. For Example, Assume i have index mapping like the following,

```
 mapping do
    indexes :id,      :type => 'integer', :index    => :not_analyzed
    indexes :col_2,   :type => 'integer', :index    => :not_analyzed
    indexes :col_3,   :type => 'date'
    indexes :col_4,   :type => 'date'

    indexes :model_2 do
      indexes :name,                  :type => 'string', :analyzer => 'whitespace'
      indexes :association_col_2,     :type => 'string', :index    => :not_analyzed
    end
 end
```

When the value of model_2.association_col_2 changes will tire automatically delta index the corresponding row in the model defined the mapping for ? How should i approach delta indexing the model on association model value changes ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tire is different to eg. Thinking Sphinx, because no delta indexing is actually happening: when your model changes, and you have included the indexing callbacks, the *whole* record serialized to JSON is sent down the wire to elasticsearch, replacing older document (keep in mind elasticsearch is actually a “searchable document database”).

If you want to trigger the callback in the parent model from the child model, you have to instrument Rails for doing so:

```
class Brake < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :car, :touch => true
end
```

See the documentation for the [ActiveRecord#touch](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/7edade337e968fb028b2b6abfa579120eb424039/activerecord/lib/active_record/persistence.rb#L296-315) method. You'll have to add a subscriber in your parent model as well, though, as documented in this *StackOverflow* answer: [Elasticsearch, Tire, and Nested queries / associations with ActiveRecord](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11692560/elasticsearch-tire-and-nested-queries-associations-with-activerecord/11711477#11711477).

Of course, you can also take care of that manually, triggering updates via observers, using background processing / messaging, etc.

Comment: This is one of the solutions that we had in mind ... Thanks Karmi !